# Attempting to enter string into file, only showing last character

Tags: python, string, file, encryption, ascii

Attempting to write a string into a new file but when I open the new file it only displays the last character. Full Encrypt is a string containing random ASCII values.

```
ciphername=input('Choose the name of the file the encrypted message will be put into: ')    
ciphertext=open(ciphername +'.txt','w')    
ciphertext.write(str(FullEncrypt))    
ciphertext.close()
```

Full Encrypt is:

```
EncryptFile=input('Enter the name of the file you wish to encrypt: ')
EightCharacterKey=''
for x in range(1,9):
    RandomNumber=random.randint(33,126)
    RandomCharacter=chr(RandomNumber)
    EightCharacterKey+=RandomCharacter
n=0
OffsetNum=0
for x in range(1,9):

    OffsetNum=ord(EightCharacterKey[n])
    n=n+1
OffsetFactor=((OffsetNum/8)-32)
OffsetFactor=int(OffsetFactor)
print(OffsetFactor)
print('Your Eight Character Key is: '+str(EightCharacterKey))
File=open(EncryptFile)
for line in File:
    print,(line)
    for letter in line:
        ConvertedText=ord(letter)
        if ConvertedText==(' '):
            pass
        FullConvertedText=ConvertedText+OffsetFactor
        if FullConvertedText>126:
            FullConvertedText=FullConvertedText-94
        print(FullConvertedText)
        FullEncrypt=str(chr(FullConvertedText))
        print(FullEncrypt)
```

If that's readable

Comment: Can you post your declaration of `FullEncrypt`?

Comment: what is `FullEncrypt`?

Answer (score 0):

Without getting into verifying the rest of your code (the so called encryption part) or optimizing it, I believe the reason for only getting the last character is because you re-assign the value of `FullEncrypt` every time you 'encrypt' a letter:

`FullEncrypt=str(chr(FullConvertedText))`

Hence, once you go over the whole file, the variable contains only the last 'encrypted' letter. And what you want to do is to append/concatenate every next letter to the variable `FullEncrypt`. One possible solution is to do:

Outside of outer `for` loop:

`FullEncrypt = ''`

And replace `FullEncrypt=str(chr(FullConvertedText))` with

`FullEncrypt += str(chr(FullConvertedText))`

PS: One good advice I can give is to use all lower letter variables with '_' between words: `full_encrypt`, `full_converted_text`. This will make your Python code much easier to read.